# Unexpected token error using async when running node.js app through systemctl only

Tags: node.js, systemctl

I have a node.js app which runs perfectly well when started through `npm start`.

But when I use a systemctl service to run it, I got an `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("` error after the `async` keyword

I checked if the node version was the same using sudo or not, and it is (10.2.1)

A previous version of the app containing `async` keywords ran fine through systemctl, so I checked the new code, to no avail (again, the new code runs perfectly through `npm start`).

Any idea ?

My .service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=CRM v2

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/html/crmv2/bin/www
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/crmv2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

package.json scripts section :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production ./bin/www",
    "test:int": "NODE_PATH=. NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 0 --recursive tests/int/ --exit"
},
```

the .bin/www script is an executable file containing JavaScript code and beginning with :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

A setup which previously worked fine

Comment: Can you post your .service file?

Comment: edited my question with the .service file

Comment: Next part to post, your package.json { "scripts": ... } section ;) `ExecStart` looks strange to me.

Comment: added. thanks a bunch

Comment: You may have multiple node installed on then machine. Check (log) output of [process.version](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.12/api/process.html#process_process_version) from inside script.

Comment: I already checked but no. Out of curiosity, I got rid off the script and used  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/html/crmv2/server.js with the same code in server.js than in .bin/www (minus the first line) and it works perfectly. Still don't understand the issue using the script though !

Comment: that's what I thought as well, it's to do the "working directory", when involving scripts, it changes. unless you need to add additional exec in the script, running node and server.js is the better way.

Comment: Ran into the same exact `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("` error after the `async` keyword as @JérômeMorlon just now when trying to get systemd to ExecStart with `npm start`. I also had no more errors once I edited my `.service` file so that it used `node` (using absolute path) and took the absolute path of my actual server file (in my case `/var/www/personal/server/index.js`). No clue why though. Anyone with insights? Thanks for asking this question.